# Show uniqueness of decimal representation using generating funcions.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I have to show using generating functions that decimal expansion of non-negative integer is unique. So I created generating function:

$$
\prod_{k=0}\sum_{i=0}^9 {x^{i \cdot 10^k}}
$$

I have to show that  coefficient of every power of $x$ is equal to $1$. In other word I have to show that constructed generating function is equal to $\sum_{i=0}x^i$. I am completely helpless maybe there is some simpler way?

Comment: As is *frequently* discussed, $0.999\ldots = 1.000\ldots$. I'm not sure what technique you're using, so maybe it accounts for this case, but if not, it won't work.

Comment: @HenrySwanson I meant non-negative integer. I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we restrict ourselves to $m+1$-digit integers. Then the generating function becomes
$$f_m(x) = \prod_{k=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^9 x^{j 10^k}.$$
Evaluating the sum this is
$$f_m(x) = \prod_{k=0}^m \frac{x^{10\times 10^k} - 1}{x^{10^k}-1}
= \prod_{k=0}^m \frac{x^{10^{k+1}} - 1}{x^{10^k}-1}.$$
This product telescopes and the only terms left over are
$$f_m(x) = \frac{x^{10^{m+1}}-1}{x-1}.$$
But this is a geometric series and
$$f_m(x) = \sum_{q=0}^{10^{m+1}-1}  x^q.$$
QED.

Comment: Whole proof is coded in two words "product relescopes" :D. I already know the answer anyway.